# Hittest in android Webview

Tags: android, webview, sdk, hittest

Is it possible to do a hittest in android WebView and get x,y coordinates.I have an indoor map which is available on a weblink.I would like the user to tap on the area of the map displayed in webview and i can call events on touch depending upon the x,y coordinate being hit.Thank

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your current code? It sounds like you will need to use OnTouchListener.

Comment: How is you map is displayed in WebView: is it an image, or an svg, or a canvas drawing?

Comment: Hi,the map iin webview is a SVG.My current code only has webview.Not sure how to proceed further to capture touch event on webview.